# Hi all i am ploting a graph between in R

Tags: r

I am plotting a graph between 2 variable in R.

Time and city are variable in city.

like my code plot(time ~ City,table)

i am getting below error message..
could you please any one advise..

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Can you show output of `dput(head(table))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the following syntax

```
plot(1:10,21:30)
```

Or, probably in your case

```
plot(table$time,table$City)
```

Good luck with it! The start is always difficult.